# flask-bcrypt - ValueError: Invalid Salt

Tags: python, flask

Имеется база данных сайта на удаленном сервере. Разрабатывая сайт локально подключаюсь к этой же базе, использовал flask-bcrypt для хеширования паролей пользователей. Локально создал пользователя, логиниться получается.Но при работе на удаленном сервере (пользуется этой же базой), залогиниться уже не получилось,происходит ошибка. Лог apache2  :

```
[2017-04-14 00:10:28,724] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST], referer: http://site.net/login
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app, referer: http://site.net/login
     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://site.net/login
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://site.net/login
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise, referer: http://site.net/login
     raise value, referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://site.net/login
     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request, referer: http://site.net/login
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "<string>", line 2, in login, referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 413, in new_func, referer: http://site.net/login
     try: return func(*args, **kwargs), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/home/www/site/main/user/views.py", line 43, in login, referer: http://site.net/login
     correct = user.check_password(password), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/home/www/site/main/user/models.py", line 57, in check_password, referer: http://site.net/login
     return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, given_password), referer: http://site.net/login
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 193, in check_password_hash, referer: http://site.net/login
     return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash), referer: http://site.net/login
   ValueError: Invalid salt, referer: http://site.net/login
```

Answer (score 0):

[На англ. стаке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548846/flask-bcrypt-valueerror-invalid-salt)
Там есть 5 вариантов решения ошибки

1. Надо декодировать пароль на одном из этапов `password.encode('utf-8')` проблема в том что там сказано что он должен автоматически его кодировать , в зависимости от питона , но в вашем случае что-то не так работает.
2. Нашел на гите `flask-bcrypt` [issue](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/issues/9) там сказано что парень просто местами параметры перепутал.
3. Пишут что перед тем как сохранять в базу надо сделать 
   `def set_password(self, pw):
   pwhash = bcrypt.hashpw(pw.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
   self.password_hash = pwhash.decode('utf8')`
4. `self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')`
5. Еще одно решение было предложено запустить апач под `mod_wsgi` и запустить все в виртуальном окружении, в `httpd.conf` после `/etc/httpd/conf.d/...` добавить /etc/httpd/conf.d/... add:

Вот такое решение тоже предложили

Ко всему в самом коде библиотеки описывает что